# D3 Horizontal grouped stacked chart bars overlap for a small number of values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created an horizontal grouped stacked chart using D3. Everything seemed perfect until I narrowed down the values to two. In the snippet below, if you replace the `json_data` with this:

```
var json_data = {"headers":["Month","Country","Number"],"rows":[["2018-05-01 00:00:00.0","France",7],["2018-05-01 00:00:00.0","Germany",19],["2018-05-01 00:00:00.0","Italy",35],["2018-05-01 00:00:00.0","Spain",40],["2018-05-01 00:00:00.0","UK",23],["2018-04-01 00:00:00.0","France",14],["2018-04-01 00:00:00.0","Germany",21],["2018-04-01 00:00:00.0","Italy",37],["2018-04-01 00:00:00.0","Spain",32],["2018-04-01 00:00:00.0","UK",129]
]};
```

everything works fine and the chart looks responsive:
[image]

However, considering that in my snippet I have two values (UK, Germany), the bars overlap. I tried playing with this line:

```
console.log(d3.scale.ordinal().rangeBands([height, 0], 0.2) );
```

but I can't think of a way to make the bars responsive no matter what the number of values is.

***Snippet:***

```js
/* ----- Data ----- */

var json_data = {"headers":["Month","Country","Number"],"rows":[["2018-05-01 00:00:00.0","Germany",19],["2018-05-01 00:00:00.0","United Kingdom",23],["2018-04-01 00:00:00.0","Germany",21],["2018-04-01 00:00:00.0","United Kingdom",129]
]};

var dataRows = json_data.rows;

/* ----- !Data ----- */

/* ----- Functions ----- */

//Create dictionary function (transformed JSON)
createDict = (data) => {
  let groups = data.reduce((acc, arr) => {
    if (acc.hasOwnProperty(arr[1])) {
      acc[arr[1]].push(arr);
    } else {
      acc[arr[1]] = [arr];
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});

  let results = [];
  for (let g in groups) {
    let obj = {Value: g};
    let a = groups[g][0];
    let b = groups[g][1];
    if (a[0] <= b[0]) {
      obj.num = a[2];
      obj.num2 = b[2];
    } else {
      obj.num = b[2];
      obj.num2 = a[2];
    }
    results.push(obj);
  }
  
  return results;
}

//Returns unique values of a specific object of a JSON string
uniqueValues = (data,objectNum) => {

var uniqueValues = [];
data.forEach(function(item) {
    var value = item[objectNum];
    if (uniqueValues.indexOf(value) !== -1)
    return false;

    uniqueValues.push(value);
});

return uniqueValues;
}

//Chart creation function
createChart = (data) => {
  //Margin conventions
  console.log(data)
  var margin = {top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 20, left: 70};

  var widther = window.outerWidth;

  var width = widther - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  //Appends the svg to the chart-container div
  var svg = d3.select(".g-chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  //Creates the xScale 
  var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0,width]);

  //Creates the yScale
  var y0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeBands([height, 0], 0.2) 
    .domain(uniqueValues);
    
    console.log(d3.scale.ordinal().rangeBands([height, 0], 0.2) );
    //.domain(["Spain", "UK", "Germany", "France", "Italy"]);

  //Defines the y axis styles
  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y0)
    .orient("left");

  //Defines the y axis styles
  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickFormat(function(d) {return d; })
    //Change axis values for percentage
    //.tickFormat(function(d) {return d + "%"; })
    .tickSize(height)
    .ticks(numTicks(width)); 

    //FORMAT data
    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.num = +d.num;
    });


    //Sets the max for the xScale
    var maxX = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.num; });

    //Defines the xScale max
    xScale.domain([0, maxX ]);

    //Appends the y axis
    var yAxisGroup = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);

    //Appends the x axis    
    var xAxisGroup = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .call(xAxis); 

    //Binds the data to the bars      
    var categoryGroup = svg.selectAll(".g-category-group")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "g-category-group")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(0," + y0(d.Value) + ")";
      });

    //Appends first bar   
    var bars = categoryGroup.append("rect")
      .attr("width", function(d) { return xScale(d.num); })
      .attr("height", y0.rangeBand()/2.5 )
      .attr("class", "g-num")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0,4)");

    //Appends second bar   
    var bars2 = categoryGroup.append("rect")
      .attr("width", function(d) { return xScale(d.num2); })
      .attr("height", y0.rangeBand()/2.5 )
      .attr("class", "g-num2")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0,29)");  

    //Binds data to labels
    var labelGroup = svg.selectAll("g-num")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "g-label-group")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(0," + y0(d.Value) + ")";
      });

    //Appends first bar labels   
    var barLabels = labelGroup.append("text") 
      .text(function(d) {return  d.num;})
      .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.num) - 20; })
      .attr("y", y0.rangeBand()/2.65 )
      .attr("class", "g-labels");    

    //Appends second bar labels   
    var barLabels2 = labelGroup.append("text") 
      .text(function(d) {return  d.num2;})
      .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.num2) - 20; })
      .attr("y", y0.rangeBand()/1.25 )
      .attr("class", "g-labels");      

    //Appends chart source
    d3.select(".g-source-bold")
      .text("SOURCE: ")
      .attr("class", "g-source-bold");

    d3.select(".g-source-reg")
      .text("Chart source info goes here")
      .attr("class", "g-source-reg");  


    //RESPONSIVENESS
    d3.select(window).on("resize", resized);

    function resized() {

      //new margin
      var newMargin = {top: 10, right: 80, bottom: 20, left: 50};

      //Get the width of the window
      var w = d3.select(".g-chart").node().clientWidth;
      console.log("resized", w);

      //Change the width of the svg
      d3.select("svg")
        .attr("width", w);

      //Change the xScale
      xScale
        .range([0, w - newMargin.right]);

      //Update the bars
      bars
        .attr("width", function(d) { return xScale(d.num); });

      //Update the second bars
      bars2
        .attr("width", function(d) { return xScale(d.num2); });  

      //Updates bar labels
      barLabels
        .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.num) - 20; })
        .attr("y", y0.rangeBand()/2.65 )

      //Updates second bar labels
      barLabels2
        .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.num2) - 20; })
        .attr("y", y0.rangeBand()/1.25 )  

      //Updates xAxis
      xAxisGroup
        .call(xAxis);   

      //Updates ticks
      xAxis
        .scale(xScale)
        .ticks(numTicks(w));

    };

  //}

  //Determines number of ticks base on width
  function numTicks(widther) {
    if (widther <= 400) {
      return 4
      console.log("return 4")
    }
    else {
      return 10
      console.log("return 5")
    }
  }
}
  
/* ----- !Functions ----- */ 

/* ----- Main ----- */

var data = createDict(dataRows);

//Calculate unique Values 
var uniqueValues = uniqueValues(dataRows,1);
 
createChart(data);

/* ----- !Main ----- */
```

```css
/*css to go here*/
  @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla);
  body {
    font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  .g-hed {
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:22px; 
    margin: 3px 0;
  }

  .g-source-bold {
    text-align: left;
    font-size:10px;
    font-weight: bold; 
  }

  .g-source {
    margin: 10px 0;
  }

  .g-source-bold {
    text-align: left;
    font-size:10px; 
  }

  .g-intro {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  }

  .g-num {
    fill:#124;
  }

   .g-num2 {
     fill:#ccc;
  }

  .g-labels {
    fill: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
  }

  .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ccc;
    stroke-dasharray: 2px 3px;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    stroke-width: 1px;
  }

  .axis text {
    font-size: 13px;
    pointer-events: none;
    fill: #7e7e7e;
  }

  .domain {
    display: none;
  }

  .y.axis text {
    text-anchor: end !important;
    font-size:14px;
    fill: #000000;
  }

  .y.axis line {
    display: none;
  }

  .g-baseline line {
    stroke:#000;
    stroke-width: 1px;
    stroke-dasharray:none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>


<body>
  <h5 class="g-hed"></h5>
  <p class="g-intro"></p>
  <div class="g-chart"></div>
    <div class="g-source"><span class="g-source-bold"></span><span class="g-source-reg"></span></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with the offset of the bars from each other; if you hard-code a value, e.g. using `translate(0,29)`, you are going to be in trouble when the chart data changes, and that makes the bars change size, too. To prevent that happening, set the translate value relative to the size of the bar:

```
//Appends first bar   
var bars = categoryGroup.append("rect")
  .attr("width", function(d) { return xScale(d.num); })
  .attr("height", y0.rangeBand()/2.5 )
  .attr("class", "g-num")

var bars2 = categoryGroup.append("rect")
  .attr("width", function(d) { return xScale(d.num2); })
  .attr("height", y0.rangeBand()/2.5 )
  .attr("class", "g-num2")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + ( y0.rangeBand()/2.5 ) + ")");
```

This way, no matter how many or how few bars you have in the chart, the offset of `bars2` will always be the same size as the height of the bars, i.e. `y0.rangeBand()/2.5`.

I'd advise you to standardise the bar label position in a similar manner, but add in a fixed `y` offset using the `dy` attribute:

```
//Appends first bar labels   
var barLabels = labelGroup.append("text") 
  .text(function(d) {return  d.num;})
  .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.num) - 20; })
  .attr("y", y0.rangeBand()/2.5 ) // note: use 2.5, rather than 2.65
  .attr('dy', '-0.35em')          // fixed y offset, set relative to the text size
  .attr("class", "g-labels");    

//Appends second bar labels   
var barLabels2 = labelGroup.append("text") 
  .text(function(d) {return  d.num2;})
  .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.num2) - 20; })
  .attr("y", y0.rangeBand()/1.25 )
  .attr('dy', '-0.35em')          // fixed y offset
  .attr("class", "g-labels");
```

Here's your full example:

```js
/* ----- Data ----- */

var json_data = {"headers":["Month","Country","Number"],"rows":[["2018-05-01 00:00:00.0","Germany",19],["2018-05-01 00:00:00.0","United Kingdom",23],["2018-04-01 00:00:00.0","Germany",21],["2018-04-01 00:00:00.0","United Kingdom",129] ]};

var dataRows = json_data.rows;

/* ----- !Data ----- */

/* ----- Functions ----- */

//Create dictionary function (transformed JSON)
createDict = (data) => {
  let groups = data.reduce((acc, arr) => {
    if (acc.hasOwnProperty(arr[1])) {
      acc[arr[1]].push(arr);
    } else {
      acc[arr[1]] = [arr];
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});

  let results = [];
  for (let g in groups) {
    let obj = {Value: g};
    let a = groups[g][0];
    let b = groups[g][1];
    if (a[0] <= b[0]) {
      obj.num = a[2];
      obj.num2 = b[2];
    } else {
      obj.num = b[2];
      obj.num2 = a[2];
    }
    results.push(obj);
  }
  
  return results;
}

//Returns unique values of a specific object of a JSON string
uniqueValues = (data,objectNum) => {

var uniqueValues = [];
data.forEach(function(item) {
    var value = item[objectNum];
    if (uniqueValues.indexOf(value) !== -1)
    return false;

    uniqueValues.push(value);
});

return uniqueValues;
}

//Chart creation function
createChart = (data) => {
  //Margin conventions
  console.log(data)
  var margin = {top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 20, left: 70};

  var widther = window.outerWidth;

  var width = widther - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  //Appends the svg to the chart-container div
  var svg = d3.select(".g-chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  //Creates the xScale 
  var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0,width]);

  //Creates the yScale
  var y0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeBands([height, 0], 0.2) 
    .domain(uniqueValues);
    
    console.log(d3.scale.ordinal().rangeBands([height, 0], 0.2) );
    //.domain(["Spain", "UK", "Germany", "France", "Italy"]);

  //Defines the y axis styles
  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y0)
    .orient("left");

  //Defines the y axis styles
  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickFormat(function(d) {return d; })
    //Change axis values for percentage
    //.tickFormat(function(d) {return d + "%"; })
    .tickSize(height)
    .ticks(numTicks(width)); 

    //FORMAT data
    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.num = +d.num;
    });


    //Sets the max for the xScale
    var maxX = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.num; });

    //Defines the xScale max
    xScale.domain([0, maxX ]);

    //Appends the y axis
    var yAxisGroup = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);

    //Appends the x axis    
    var xAxisGroup = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .call(xAxis); 

    //Binds the data to the bars      
    var categoryGroup = svg.selectAll(".g-category-group")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "g-category-group")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(0," + y0(d.Value) + ")";
      });

    //Appends first bar   
    var bars = categoryGroup.append("rect")
      .attr("width", function(d) { return xScale(d.num); })
      .attr("height", y0.rangeBand()/2.5 )
      .attr("class", "g-num")
//      .attr("transform", "translate(0,4)");

    //Appends second bar   
    var bars2 = categoryGroup.append("rect")
      .attr("width", function(d) { return xScale(d.num2); })
      .attr("height", y0.rangeBand()/2.5 )
      .attr("class", "g-num2")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + ( y0.rangeBand()/2.5 ) + ")");  

    //Binds data to labels
    var labelGroup = svg.selectAll("g-num")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "g-label-group")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(0," + y0(d.Value) + ")";
      });

    //Appends first bar labels   
    var barLabels = labelGroup.append("text") 
      .text(function(d) {return  d.num;})
      .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.num) - 20; })
      .attr("y", y0.rangeBand()/2.5 )
      .attr('dy', '-0.35em')
      .attr("class", "g-labels");    

    //Appends second bar labels   
    var barLabels2 = labelGroup.append("text") 
      .text(function(d) {return  d.num2;})
      .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.num2) - 20; })
      .attr("y", y0.rangeBand()/1.25 )
      .attr('dy', '-0.35em')
      .attr("class", "g-labels");      

    //Appends chart source
    d3.select(".g-source-bold")
      .text("SOURCE: ")
      .attr("class", "g-source-bold");

    d3.select(".g-source-reg")
      .text("Chart source info goes here")
      .attr("class", "g-source-reg");  


    //RESPONSIVENESS
    d3.select(window).on("resize", resized);

    function resized() {

      //new margin
      var newMargin = {top: 10, right: 80, bottom: 20, left: 50};

      //Get the width of the window
      var w = d3.select(".g-chart").node().clientWidth;
      console.log("resized", w);

      //Change the width of the svg
      d3.select("svg")
        .attr("width", w);

      //Change the xScale
      xScale
        .range([0, w - newMargin.right]);

      //Update the bars
      bars
        .attr("width", function(d) { return xScale(d.num); });

      //Update the second bars
      bars2
        .attr("width", function(d) { return xScale(d.num2); });  

      //Updates bar labels
      barLabels
        .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.num) - 20; })
        .attr("y", y0.rangeBand()/2.65 )

      //Updates second bar labels
      barLabels2
        .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.num2) - 20; })
        .attr("y", y0.rangeBand()/1.25 )  

      //Updates xAxis
      xAxisGroup
        .call(xAxis);   

      //Updates ticks
      xAxis
        .scale(xScale)
        .ticks(numTicks(w));

    };

  //}

  //Determines number of ticks base on width
  function numTicks(widther) {
    if (widther <= 400) {
      return 4
      console.log("return 4")
    }
    else {
      return 10
      console.log("return 5")
    }
  }
}
  
/* ----- !Functions ----- */ 

/* ----- Main ----- */

var data = createDict(dataRows);

//Calculate unique Values 
var uniqueValues = uniqueValues(dataRows,1);
 
createChart(data);

/* ----- !Main ----- */
```

```css
/*css to go here*/
  @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla);
  body {
    font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  .g-hed {
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:22px; 
    margin: 3px 0;
  }

  .g-source-bold {
    text-align: left;
    font-size:10px;
    font-weight: bold; 
  }

  .g-source {
    margin: 10px 0;
  }

  .g-source-bold {
    text-align: left;
    font-size:10px; 
  }

  .g-intro {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  }

  .g-num {
    fill:#124;
  }

   .g-num2 {
     fill:#ccc;
  }

  .g-labels {
    fill: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
  }

  .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ccc;
    stroke-dasharray: 2px 3px;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    stroke-width: 1px;
  }

  .axis text {
    font-size: 13px;
    pointer-events: none;
    fill: #7e7e7e;
  }

  .domain {
    display: none;
  }

  .y.axis text {
    text-anchor: end !important;
    font-size:14px;
    fill: #000000;
  }

  .y.axis line {
    display: none;
  }

  .g-baseline line {
    stroke:#000;
    stroke-width: 1px;
    stroke-dasharray:none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>


<body>
  <h5 class="g-hed"></h5>
  <p class="g-intro"></p>
  <div class="g-chart"></div>
    <div class="g-source"><span class="g-source-bold"></span><span class="g-source-reg"></span></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @i alarmed alien That works for that purpose but the overall is losing its responsiveness when I make the screen (width) smaller).

Comment: I have actually changed that. You changed the `innerWidth` to `outerWidth`.

Comment: My bad. Dunno how. I possibly pasted an older version. Still surprised as this was the first thing I changed.

Comment: As long as the vertical bar fix works, it doesn't matter too much. :)